# Database query using array in ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to find all rows with value in array, This is my code

```
require 'sqlite3'
db = SQLite3::Database.new('test.sqlite')
res = db.query("SELECT w1.synsetid
                FROM words w1
                WHERE w1.wordid IN (?)", arr)
```

arr: array of strings

And I get this error

```
SQLite3::RangeException: bind or column index out of range
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to [`query`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/SQLite3/Database%3aquery) is meant to be an array of placeholder values:

> `- (Object) query(sql, bind_vars = [], *args)`
>
> This is a convenience method for creating a statement, binding
>   paramters to it, and calling execute:

The `query` method doesn't know that it should treat your `arr` array specially, it just sees one placeholder and multiple values.

I think you have to do this this hard way: build the appropriate number of placeholders and paste them into the SQL. Something like this:

```
placeholders = (['?'] * arr.length).join(',')
res = db.query("select ... where w1.wordid in (#{placeholders})", arr)
```

You know exactly what is in `placeholders` so you don't have to worry about using string interpolation and injection issues when building your SQL like this.

If you're using Rails already then you could also wrap your SQLite tables with ActiveRecord and then use the usual ActiveRecord interface:

```
words = Word.where(:wordid => arr)
```