# Joining array of strings into a quoted comma-separated list

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

If I have a array of strings like so:

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

How would I convert it into a backtick-quoted comma-separated string like so:

```
"`one`, `two`, `three`"
```

I have accomplished it using three calls like so:

```
arr = arr.join "`, `"
arr = arr.prepend "`"
arr = arr += "`"
```

but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to achieve this or if there was a better function to use besides `join`. Preferably a one liner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three"]

arr
  .map { |e| "`#{e}`" }
  .join(', ')
```

You could even put it on a single line:

```
arr.map { |e| "`#{e}`" }.join(', ')
```

Now, I'm not entirely sure of this, but it looks like you might be using this to perhaps quote parameters for an SQL query? If you are, then please don't do it like this, but use a proper SQL escaping function or parameterized queries.

---

In response to the confirmation that you're using this for an SQL query, a better way would be to use (assuming you're using [sqlite3-ruby](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby)):

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new 'my_database.sqlite3'
arr = ["one", "two", "three"]

db.execute('select * from foo where a=? and b=? and c=?', arr) do |row|
  p row
end
```

This will make sure it always works. Adding backticks may seem like a good idea at first, but:

- There are ways to work around this and do an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. This is bad and allows anyone to read or destroy data.
- Even if it's just for personal use, it's good to do it the "proper way", since sooner or later you'll run into the problem that your data has a ` or some other special character you didn't think of, at which point your program breaks.

Comment: Yes I am doing this to escape a list of variables for a SQL query. I will look to see if the SQLite3 gem provides a proper escaping function. I would use parameterized queries, but I am not sure if they support dynamic sized lists for use with the `IN` SQL clause.

Comment: @randynewfield My hunch was correct :-) See the updated answer. It's really simple to use (probably simpler than *not* doing it!)

Comment: unfortunately I can't use parameterized queries like that since my clause where I need to craft the string is being used in the `IN` clause (http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php) where my array will vary in length and cannot be hard coded to a parameterized constant number of variables.

Comment: @randynewfield might I recommend active_record it will handle this no problem in hash syntax e.g. `Some Object.where(some_column: arr)`. This is the underpinnings for rails queries and is extremely robust. It may require a bit more formal development but even outside rails I have found it to be extremely useful.

Comment: This answer describes how to bind an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605253/database-query-using-array-in-ruby